# Is Lex automatically included

Tags: c++, lex

I would like to know if [Lex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lex_%28software%29) is included in C++ or you have to download it from somewhere and import?

Comment: Could you tell us what Lex is?

Comment: @Default: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lex_%28software%29

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, [`lex`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lex_%28software%29) is not "included in C++". It is not part of the C++ standard, and I am not aware of any C++ compiler that would include it out of the box (as a non-standard extension).

You have to download it separately.

A popular implementation is [`flex`](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/).

Comment: Note that `flex` isn't quite the same as `lex` (although I think it has a compatibility mode).  But that it is probably more widely spread and used than `lex`.  (Is `lex` even maintained any more.)